# How to make an irregular quadrilateral shaped button in kivy python?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am trying to make an android app with kivy. Its user interface begins with these two buttons named '2D' and '3D'. Please help me to create a irregular quadrilateral shaped button with kivy.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `Button` to behave as though it is two `Buttons`:

```
class MyButton(Button):
    my_state = StringProperty('')  # this will be 'b1' or 'b2', even when button is not down
    my_down_image = StringProperty('')
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            rx, ry = self.to_widget(*touch.pos, relative=True)
            if ry > self.height/2.0:  # more complex geometry calculation required
                self.my_down_image = 'B2Down.png'
                self.my_state = 'b2'
            else:
                self.my_down_image = 'B1Down.png'
                self.my_state = 'b1'
        return super(MyButton, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```

The `MyButton` class adds two properties to `Button`, the `my_state` and`my_down_image` properties. The `my_state` property will be `b1` or `b2` depending on which sub-button was pressed (set by `on_touch_down()`). The `my_down_image` property is set to either `B1Down.png` or `B2Down.png` which depict what we want the `MyButton` to look like when `B1` or `B2` is pressed. The simple y-coordinate compare that is in the above code will not work, and must be more complicated to correctly determine which sub-button was pressed. The `MyButton` can be used in `kv` like this:

```
MyButton:
    background_normal: 'B1andB2.png'
    on_press: app.do_butt_press(self)
    on_release: app.do_butt_release(self)
```

where the `app` methods look like:

```
def do_butt_press(self, button):
    print('on_butt_press', button.state, button.my_state)

def do_butt_release(self, button):
    print('on_butt_release', button.state, button.my_state)
```

and in `kv`:

```
<-MyButton>:
    state_image: self.background_normal if self.state == 'normal' else self.my_down_image
    disabled_image: self.background_disabled_normal if self.state == 'normal' else self.background_disabled_down
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color
        BorderImage:
            border: self.border
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: self.disabled_image if self.disabled else self.state_image
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            texture: self.texture
            size: self.texture_size
            pos: int(self.center_x - self.texture_size[0] / 2.), int(self.center_y - self.texture_size[1] / 2.)
```

The above `kv` rule is mostly just a copy of the default `Button` rule used by Kivy. The only change is the use of `my_down_image` in the `state_image` definition.

For this example, the `B1andB2.png` can be:

[image: B1andB2.png]

`B1Down.png`:

[image: B1Down.png]

and `B2Down.png`:
[image: B2Down.png]